# Commercial Baking On A Convection Oven and Its Effects on the HVac

Tags: electrical, hvac

I would like to ask how badly or how strongly would a double convection oven pull on a 3 ton commercial HVac, within a bakery? I am looking to open a bakery and liked the idea of using a convection oven to make my products, mainly because the installation of a hood and ventilation for right now is out of the question. As I started making decisions on which convection oven to get, I began to realize an electric convection oven would be the best way to go. Having a double electric convection just makes sense due to the load I would need to produce daily.

My question before I purchase the oven is, since I am responsible as the leasee for the maintenance of it, what effects on this 3 ton Hvac should I expect for daily usage of the double convection oven and would baking daily blow it out and how quickly( I was assuming the air conditioning would be used the most and the main reason it would go out, if it did at all)? Time frame in months/ years. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because commercial kitchens are outside the scope of this site

Answer (score 2):

Much more information is needed to even make an educated guess in providing an answer to your question. Some information needed is: 1) how large of an oven do you want and what is it's wattage; 2) how much room venting will be done; 3) does the A?C cool only this space or does it cool other parts of the building.

In a commercial bakery, they never try to cool the space where the oven sits. That would require way too much cooling capacity. In any of the bakeries that I serviced, An exhaust hood and fresh air intake system is what is used to ventilate the space to  remove the excess heat. Each watt of the oven will produce 3.4BTU of heat. So, a 10,000watt over will use almost all the capacity of the 3 ton (36,000 BTU) A/C system. Also, according to the head bakers that I have dwelt with say that incoming fresh air or the cool air from the A/C system can not blow directly onto the finished product as it comes from the oven.

Comment: Thank you. I found your comment useful, and I am sure there will be others with the same concern ( to that person who wanted to vote to delete)